# Is this a MinGW bug?

Tags: c++, c, mingw

I have been trying to execute this program on my MinGW, through Code::Blocks:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
int p[N];
int pr[N];
int cnt;

void sieve()
{
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<N;i++) pr[i]=1;
   pr[0]=pr[1]=0;

   for(i=2;i<N;i++)
      if(pr[i])
        {
         p[cnt]=i; cnt++;
         for(j=i+i;j<=N;j+=i) pr[j]=0;
        }

  }

int main(){
    sieve();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
       printf("%d ",p[i]);
    puts("");
   printf("Total number of prime numbers : %d",cnt);
  return 0;
}
```

On my system the output is:

**7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97

Total number of prime numbers : 22**

Which is completely insane, since I am completely sure about the implementation of my algorithm.

So I decided to try it in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/xddLq) where it gives correct output. Can anybody point out the reason ?

I changed it to N, but the output doesn't change.

Comment: Why does `p` only have two elements? (`N / 64`?) EDIT: whoops, my math sucks. It's ONE element.

Comment: @avakar I though 100/64 would be truncated to 1, making this an array of size 1. Am I missing something? EDIT: Ninja-edit faster than me.

Comment: A hint - compiler bugs are orders of magnitude rarer than bugs in your own code - they should be the last thing you think about when trying to solve a problem, not the first.

Comment: When one asks "is there a bug in <some compiler> ?!" the good answer **very often** is: "no, check your code again".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two important bugs in your code.

One is that your p array is too small, so you are writing off the end of it. This is undefined behaviour, though on the platforms you are using it overwrites the start of the pr array. This has no effect on the output, since the location you are overwriting is before the location you are testing in the sieve.

The other is that you are also writing off the end of your `pr` array:

```
        for(j=i+i;j<=N;j+=i) pr[j]=0;
```

This loops sets `pr[N]` to zero, which is off the end of `pr`. In MinGW this is where `cnt` is stored, so each time `i` divides `N`, `cnt` is set to zero. As `N` is 100, this happens for `i==2` and `i==5`, so you lose the primes before five from your result. IdeOne seems to put `cnt` somewhere else in relation to `pr`, so it does not get overwritten. This is why you get different output with the different compilers.

Change the size of the array p to N, or use only one array for both sieve and output, and change `<=` in line 18 to `<` so you don't write off the end of it.

```
int p[N];
int *pr = p; // reuse the array
```

Comment: Good catch on the writing past end of `pr`.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's actually known as a Debanjan bug :-) Have a look at *this*:

```
#define N 100
int p[N / 64];
```

It looks to me like you only allow enough space to store *one* prime in the `p` array. That means writing to `p[X]` for `X > 0` is likely to overwrite other values.

This is the dreaded undefined behavior which means that *anything* can happen (including it working as in the Ideone situation).

Just use:

```
int p[N];
```

to declare the array. I'm pretty certain there won't be more than 100 primes less than or equal to 100 :-)

Comment: Although this is *a* bug, did you actually test whether making this change has any effect on the output?

Comment: No, I tend to stop at undefined behaviour simply because all bets are off at that point. But, since you went the extra yards and found the _actual_ bug, here's an upvote for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your array, `p`, only has one element since you're declaring it with the integer division, `100/64`.

Change it to

```
int p[N];
```

or something that has at least 25 elements.

Comment: What I wonder is, why does his code not crash? Is he just lucky here?

Comment: @Space, undefined behaviour is exactly that: undefined. It means literally anything can happen, up to and including the destruction of the entire multiverse. _One_ of the many things that can happen is that it will work :-)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y the compilers happen to put `pr` is next to `p`, so writing off the end of `p` just writes into `pr`, which is harmless - cnt is always less than i, so you could even use the same array for sieving and for output. The *real* bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: he's getting lucky (or something). In my test run, I got even luckier - I got the correct output. As pasdiablo said, undefined behavior means anything can happen.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: there's no guarantee that the compiler/linker will place variables in the same order you see them in the source. In fact, one toolset I use almost never does that - even in debug builds.

Comment: @Michael that's why I said that they 'happen to' put them there.

Comment: @Pete: fair enough, but I'm not sure I agree with the characterization of this not being "the real bug" (though you definitively did catch another, more subtle bug). My compile/run of the original code in MinGW 3.4.5 produced all 25 primes and the correct count, but there are still (at least) two real bugs in the code.

Comment: @Michael yes; I meant it was not the bug which was causing the output to differ between the compilers, not that unintentionally exploiting undefined behaviour of the stack layout wasn't a bug.

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't believe that there is a MinGW bug in this case.

There is a bug in your application. As people previously mentioned the *p* array has **only 1 element**. (100/64 = 1 when dealing with integer values).

This means that when you access after *p[1] or p[2] or p[3]* (out of array bounds) you will actually access the zone memory after *p* which is the *pr* array.

With Ideone I believe it is possible that the memory zones of the arrays can be at greater distance, not one after the other like in the MinGW case (this is just an assumption).

Answer (score 0):

The array `p` is too small and you are going to overrun it and write into `pr`.

Change:

```
int p[N / 64];
```

to:

```
int p[N / 2];
```

---

Foonote: never assume a compiler bug just because you see a problem that you can't immediately explain. 99.999% of the time it will be *your* bug - you just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

100/64 is 1. So the p has only one element - p[0]. When you access p[1], p[2], etc you start overwriting elements in pr array. Which produces wrong result.

This is a bug in your program, not a mingw bug.